# How can I pass a direct link to download some file from the browser in a Code Igniter based website? Like this: www.example.com/examplemovie.mov

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I need to allow a link like this `www.example.com/example.mov` to be accessed or downloaded via browser in a code igniter application. Right now i received a "Page not found" message. The file is in the root directory, but i think there is some config in Code Igniter not allowing this behavior.

Comment: do you have assets or public folder ? put this file into these folders and try ?

Comment: GDB, i don´t have this folders. This site was made by other person and I´m just trying to help a friend. This link was printed in a book and need to work like I said. All CI files are in the public_html folder...maybe is some path config, I´m trying to figure out what can be, but I´m not a expert in CI. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have a folder named uploads. If I try www.example.com/uploads/example.mov its works. But, this is not what I need.

Comment: Thank you GDB, I put my file in uploads folder and made a redirect in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a full url make sure you enter it as a full url ie http://www.example.com/example.mov if it's a relative url on your server and it's in the root use this:

```
<?php echo base_url().'example.mov'; ?>
```

Update, based on the file working from another location you could add this line to the .htaccess file in the root (the one in the same folder where the application folder is, not inside the application folder)

```
Redirect http://www.example.com/example.mov http://example.com/uploads/example.mov
```

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your answer. But, this is the scenario: my client published a book and print this link to your readers. They'll put this link in their browsers and download the file...The file is there but i keep receiving "page not found". I'm wondering if is there some config in CI not allowing to download this file, some path, extension, route, or security related stuff. I´m totally newbie in code igniter...

Comment: A direct link from outside of CI should work. Strange. Must admit I'm curious as to who put the downvote and why? The answer was legitimate...

Comment: I´m curious too...well, it doesn´t work. I´m thinking it's something related to path configuration, but I don't know what.

Comment: I have a folder named uploads. If I try www.example.com/uploads/example.mov its works. But, this is not what I need.

Comment: Could try setting up a redirect through his hosting cpanel, or through the .htaccess file to redirect the url in the book to the uploads url. That should work

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to create some form of download management system and would prefer to not have direct links to the file out in the wild you could use the download helper:

```
$this->load->helper('download');

$data = file_get_contents("/path/to/example.mov"); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'example.mov';

force_download($name, $data);
```